# Unable to make CURL post request using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, curl

I read some Q&As but still struggling with this one. I need to post a specific array to an API and get another array as an answer.

UPDATE

I used :

```
<?php

echo 'Testing cURL<br>';

// Get cURL resource
   $curl = curl_init();
   $data=array(array("UserId"=>"xxxx-10100","Password"=>"pass"));
   $sendpostdata = json_encode( array( "postdata"=> $data ) );
   echo $sendpostdata;
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://cloud.servicebridge.com/api/v1/Login',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Accept: application/json','Content-Type: application/json'),
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request',
  CURLOPT_POST => 1,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $sendpostdata
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
  $resp = curl_exec($curl);
  echo $resp;
// Close request to clear up some resources
  curl_close($curl);

?>
```

This results in

`Testing cURL
{"postdata":[{"UserId":"xxxxx-10100","Password":"pass"}]}
{ "Data": null, "Success": false, "Error": { "Message": "Invalid UserId: ", "Value": "InvalidUserId", "Code": 9001 } }`

No console logs, no other messages or clues
I am trying to implement this API https://cloud.servicebridge.com/developer/index#/
 to Worpdress.

The API requires a

`{
    "UserId": "string",
    "Password": "string"
   }`

Can you help me out? What am I doing wrong

Really appreciate this,

Giannis

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. It didn't produce any errors, but it's a useful knowledge for the future

Comment: the thing is that when I use the exact same strings in the API test site https://cloud.servicebridge.com/developer/index#/ they work. I just copy-paste. There must be something else

Comment: and what abou the `"Data": null "` in the responce body? Do you think it's related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked the given `API` and it's `REQUEST Parameters to access them` and I think your initial data `(username and password)` is not going correctly. Please use this code:-

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); // check all type of errors
ini_set('display_errors',1); // display those errors
// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
$sendpostdata = json_encode(array("UserId"=>"xxxx-10100","Password"=>"pass"));
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://cloud.servicebridge.com/api/v1/Login',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Accept: application/json','Content-Type: application/json'),
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request',
  CURLOPT_POST => 1,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $sendpostdata
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
echo $resp;
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
?>
```

Note:- change `UserId` & `Password`values to your real values.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might help you in generating proper json. Hope this will work.

**use this**

```
   $data=array(array("UserId"=>"xxxxx-10100","Password"=>"pass"));
```

**instead of**

```
   $data ='[{"UserId":"xxxxx-10100","Password": "pass"}]';
```

Comment: please check update, thank you very much for the suggestion. the POST is submitted now.